# How can one disable Telegram global search results from showing?

Tags: search, full-text-search, telegram

Does any know how to disable Telegram global search results (GSRs)? I removed my username (which was apparently what causes one to be included on the GSRs), I then logged out of all active sessions and logged back in and tested, and I still got all the GSRs.

#telegram #disable #globalsearchresults #freedomofchoice

Comment: No one on the internet have a solution for this?
What about in the metaverse?

#telegram #disable #globalsearchresults #freedomofchoice #metaverse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your intention correctly, you do not want to see other users/bots/channels when typing smth in search field and only want to see messages from your chats corresponding the search pattern. Removing username should make you not appearing in other people's global search results, but you'll still get other publicly available users, bots and channels in your GSRs. Here is how you can change this behavior.

For desktop, you can use 64gram fork of official telegram client https://github.com/TDesktop-x64/tdesktop. It contains enhanced settings, and since v1.1.12 these settings contain option allowing to disable global search. Here is where you can find it: <Side menu> -> Settings -> Enhanced Settings -> <Messages subsection> -> Disable global search.

Download (Windows, Linux, MacOS): https://github.com/TDesktop-x64/tdesktop/releases

For Android, you can use Nagram fork of official telegram client https://github.com/NextAlone/Nagram. The corresponding settings can be found here: <Side menu> -> Settings -> N-Settings -> Chat -> Disable global search

Download (Android): https://github.com/NextAlone/Nagram/releases. If you are using a more or less fresh device, the v8a version should be suitable for you. If you get an error during installation, try the v7a version.

Comment: What about for iPhone, kovdan01 ?